# while paypal integration , I entered email and password , I'm getting " Login Failed ->System error.please try again later dialog"

Tags: kotlin, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

[I'm getting this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGk4v.jpg)

```
   implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'

   val intent = Intent(this, PayPalService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config)
    startService(intent)

   private var config =
    PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        .clientId(AppConstants.getPayPalClientID())

   val payment = PayPalPayment(
        BigDecimal(7),
        "USD",
        "abcd",
        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_ORDER
    )
    payment.invoiceNumber(getting this from my backend)


    val intent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java)

    // send the same configuration for restart resiliency

    // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config)

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment)

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
```

The above-implemented code is for Paypal payment,
Is the above-implemented code is correct or not

below provided my error
for the above code, I'm getting the below exception

```
 E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:404,exception:
2021-01-28 17:16:05.886 7263-10006/{package name} E/paypal.sdk: Exception parsing server 
response
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.cw.m(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.fm.d(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.ci.a(Unknown Source:21)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.a(Unknown Source:58)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.cq.onResponse(Unknown Source:45)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2021-01-28 17:16:05.887 7263-10006/{package name} E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server 
 response:
   2021-01-28 17:16:05.890 7263-7263/{package name} E/paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

please give the solution for this,
anyone have a Paypal mobile SDK integration, please give the blog

Comment: Did you find a solution ? same is happening with me. i cannot move to Braintree as they are not accepting accounts for anyone there are thousands of complaints for Braintree account, it's been 8 months our account is not being registered. If you have found a solution please share.

Comment: I got solution through this blog. 
https://medium.com/tilicholabs/paypal-checkout-integration-in-android-d9cd39233893 Please give a try

Answer (score 0):

That SDK has been deprecated for years and is now sunset (end of life). It cannot be used.

If you need a native SDK for PayPal payments, use Braintree's. Here is some documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/ , the rest of it is on Braintree's site. Do not create a gateway account. Use an access token from the bottom of [developer.paypal.com applications](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) for authentication to your PayPal account.  You will need a webservice to get the client token.

For a non-native integration, use [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/)

Comment: i cannot move to Braintree as they are not accepting accounts for anyone there are thousands of complaints for Braintree account, it's been 8 months our account is not being registered.

Comment: To use their SDK for PayPal payments, specifically, you do not need a Braintree account. See what I wrote above for how to get a Braintree access token for your PayPal account.